# How to find all the links in a website without actually going there using jquery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, web

I am new in jquery please suggest me a simple and easy to learn code for finding all the links in external website without actually going there using JQuery the code I am trying os this  `urls = $$('a'); for (url in urls) console.log(urls[url].href);` but it works only if we are on the page of which we want to get links, I can also prefer php but not so complex or more simply I want to say how to create a Web Spider using JQuery or Hypertext Preprocessor [PHP] like the one which was made by Google.

Comment: What do you mean 'without actually going there'?

Comment: I think he wants to create a cross domain request.

Comment: Well, its many time not possible to find number of links due to http headers. Secondly, show some code or work or some reference you are talking about

Comment: I mean there is a code urls = $$('a'); for (url in urls) console.log(urls[url].href); it print all the links in developer console but the problem is we have to be on that page for the error less execution of this code means if we are not on the page of which we want all the links and execute that code then it will put an error on developer console.

Comment: Please clarify and provide some code to help us understand.  It might be difficult to do with jQuery.  Yet, you can do it on the server side. Here is an open source example that might help: [PHP-Crawler](http://astellar.com/php-crawler/)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that without visiting. At least You've to parse contents of page with CURL at serverside and echo them to your client browser.
You can use phpQuery to get all links from html contents.

```
1. https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/downloads/list - phpQuery-onefile and extract it to public directory. for example create a folder "parsers" in public and put it there.

2. create get-urls.php file and put it to parsers directory in public directory (near with phpquery)

    <?php

    require_once('phpQuery-onefile.php');

    $document = phpQuery::newDocumentFileHTML($_GET['url'], $charset = 'utf-8');

    $links = $document->find('a');
    $result = array();
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        $href = pq($link)->attr('href');
        $result[] = $href;
    }

    echo json_encode($result);

3. at clientside (on page where you want to get links) call your serverside script and pass your url and get answer

    <script>
    $(function(){
       $.get('http://yourserver.com/parsers/get-urls.php', {'url': 'some_url_here'}, function(response){
          response = $.parseJSON(response);
          for(var r in response) {
             var link = response[r];
             console.log(link);
          }
       });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: when I execute your code on my developer console it put an error.

Comment: Or if I have to execute it in a php file on a local server then how to put javascript inside php.

Comment: thanks for your help but I think I didn't applied your code correctly as I can't understand it yet.

Comment: Nice answer and probably the best one OP will get.  Here is the documentation for [phpquery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Manual)